# Android Studio 3 build APK with NOX file type

Tags: apk, android-studio-3.0

I had problem with running any android emulator on my AMD PC and have tried NOX player. It doesn't work and has been uninstaled. But when I build APK now, all created APKs are NOX.apk files and of course doesn't run on real phones. Anybody knows how to get rid of these annoying NOX file type by generating APK?? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Finally found solution by myself!
Need to go to regedit file and in HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, find .apk extention. Click right button on NAME and select 'Modify'. Then remove 'NOX.apk' and ready. Android Studio will build just ordinary .apk files.

Comment: Did you entered any text in value field after removing nox.apk from it or kept it blank?